# Synonyms of いかに

Tags: grammar, words, synonyms

Could the word いかに always be replaced by どんなに／いくら／どれだけ／どれほど／なんと in structures like

1. いかに～か
2. いかに～ても／でも
3. いかに～とも
4. いかに～ことか

Basically, what I would like to know is if いかに and どんなに／いくら／どれだけ／どれほど／なんと are considered synonyms or there is any difference.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. - いかに [adj.] か "How [adj.] (it) is!" (exclamatory)
     = どんなに／どれだけ／どれほど／なんと
   - いかに [V] か "how to V"
     = どう／どのように／どうやって
2. - いかに [adj.] ても／でも "no matter how [adj.]"
     = どんなに／いくら／どれだけ／どれほど／どれくらい
   - いかに [V] ても "no matter how [V]"
     = どんなに／いくら／どれだけ／どれほど／どれくらい (how much)
     = どう／どのように／どうやって (in what manner)
3. = #2 except verbs' conjugation (also often become volitional form "no matter how (it) *would/should* [V]")
4. - いかに [adj./V] ことか "How [adj./V-ing] (it) is!" (explicitly exclamatory)
     = どんなに／どれだけ／どれほど／なんと
     (only such verbs that is semantically stative could be used)

Basically いか is an older word that has double face of "how much" and "what manner/type". To make things more complex, it is often involved in idiomatic or largely fixed expressions, which you have asked. There are only limited forms how いか is employed today:

- いかに: (degree) どんなに／いくら etc.; (manner) どう／どのように etc.
- いかなる: どんな／どのような "what kind of"
- いかが: どう "how about; what about; what like"
- [いかん](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF-ikan-dewa/) (almost a particle; better see the link)
- [いかんせん](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93/) "unfortunately"

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! とても助かりました! :)