# Difference between どれだけ、どれほど、 and どんなに

Tags: grammar

It seems that these words have a similar meaning when used in a specific grammar construction:

- どれだけ
- どれほど
- どんなに

どんなに／どれほど/どれだけ　+ verbても/Aくても/Nでも

For example:

- (どれだけ/どんなに／どれほど)聞いても意味が分からない
- (どれだけ/どんなに/どれほど)説明しても、あの人はわかってくれない

Does the meaning change at all if you use one over the other?

Comment: I’d also like to include the similar usage of: いくら。。。でも。。。

Comment: They are mostly synonymous https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80100/45489